# How to cache a collection via Russian Doll in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, haml

I have the following snippet in haml under Rails 4.2.6, where I render a day full of records, then move to the next day.  I'd like to use Russian Doll caching to speed the page load, which is rendering up to 300 tickets, but I'm not sure how to create the cache key for the collection--

cache key for `@tickets.where(calendar_date: day).order(:calendar_order)`?

Then I need to cache individual tickets.  Please consider, by the time I ask for help here, I am a bit confused.  So if my question seems unclear, please let me clarify if that is needed.

Note that the `day` variable is incremented earlier in the code.

```
.row(data-row-date="#{ day }")
  - @tickets.where(calendar_date: day).order(:calendar_order).each do |t|
    - cache(t) do 
      # code for each job ticket
```

UPDATE

The following code works better than my previous attempts, but I'm not sure if it's accurate, whether the keys will expire correctly.

```
.row(data-row-date="#{ day }")
  - tickets = @tickets.where(calendar_date: day).order(:calendar_order)
  - cache(["day-#{day}", tickets.map(&:id), tickets.maximum(:updated_at)]) do
    - tickets.each do |t|
      - cache(t) do
```

Will you tell me if I'm on the right track?  Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Russian doll caching" usually means a kind of caching when outdated nested resources invalidate cache for their parent recources automatically (e.g. `user` digest gets outdated along with `ticket` digest when ticket info is updated).

I'm not sure if you're going to add some level of nesting later (it would require a little more effort to set up `touch: true` for model relations), but for now it seems pretty fine to me:

1. each ticket is cached (Rails gonna make a md5 based on an object `t`);
2. as long as you request tickets for the same day and your result set is not changed, you show the whole cached block instead of (1).

A couple of issues I can imagine include:

1. Different timezones. In case your `calendar_date` is actually a `Date`, users from different parts of the globe might want to get results based on their actual date, not a server-based one;
2. Note that ActiveRecord will not update the timestamp fields (updated_at/updated_on) when using `update_all`. Beware of doing something like `Ticket.update_all(params)` as it won't invalidate your cache digest.

Comment: I make a nested cache for each `day`. So far it seems to be working well, about 2Mb on heroku redis. Thank you.

Comment: the date is a Date object, and the app is for one office group in Dallas, so they won't need different timezones.  I don't think I'm using `update_all` anywhere, and I'll keep that in mind (as best I can). Thank you.